# Modify hue saturation of a cameraPreview at runTime

Tags: java, android, camera, arrays

> How can i modify **saturation, color hue and contrast of CameraPreview** . is there way any for apply saturation, color hue, contrast on live camera.

How can we set these params after getting byte[] array.

```
camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                        Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I want to change these parameter using three seekbar and those parameter must be set to live Camera.

Comment: Is your need to change the way the preview is displayed on screen, or actually effect the ISP parameters?

Comment: I have achieved it by converting the bytes to rgb and then simply changing red,green,blue factor. after converting to rgb. you can find a lot of source on google for changing hue,contrast and saturation